# scrapy:send log to email

Tags: python, scrapy

I have question
When I run scrapy,it will creat 3 log files,and I will open them to see if there is error
But now I have to push my code to remote server.
So I want to let the log message can send to my email

I look document,but still have no idea(Where to put these code or how to write the body with my log)

```
from scrapy.mail import MailSender
mailer = MailSender()
mailer.send(to=["someone@example.com"], subject="Some subject", body="Some body", cc=["another@example.com"])
```

My code like this:

```
class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "shop"
    start_urls = []

    def __init__(self):
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider.log", 'w'), level=log.INFO).start()             
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider_error.log", 'w'), level=log.ERROR).start()     
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider_warning.log", 'w'), level=log.WARNING).start()  
        super(ProductSpider, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
         ......
```

Can someone give me direction.Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look into setting up a scrapyd server on your remote device. This will give you full access to all logs plus a nice api for scheduling spiders and updating your project. I've used it and it is very easy to set up and convenient to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add extension in your project and your code there under closed_spider

[a Scrapy Extensions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html)

and add your extension in your settings.py , e.g

```
    EXTENSIONS = {
'scrapy.contrib.corestats.CoreStats': 500,
'scrapy.webservice.WebService': 500,
'scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole': 500,
```

}

and also you can look at this [a source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/statsmailer.py)

I hope you will get your solution.